# How to merge custom androidmanifest.xml and generated one?

Tags: android, qt, android-manifest

I want to add autorun to qt android application.

For that I take generated AndroidManifest.xml file from build directory,  manually add required strings and put it to ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR directory (and it works).

The problem is that the generated AndroidManifest.xml can change and thats why I don't want to add resulting manifest to repository.

I want to add only manifest with my strings and I don't know how.

In compile output I see:

```
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
```

Can I enable manifest merger?

Comment: I don't know if you can enable manifest merger but you can create a manifest from Qt Creator and edit it through Creator or manually. This way the manifest is not generated for you during the build. http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html

Comment: talamaki: this is what I do. And I want to: 

1) put MyManifest.xml (small)  to git repository
2) add lines generated by qt to it (QtManigest.xml) 
3) get  in android build: AndroidManifest.xml = MyManifest.xml + QtManigest.xml

Comment: Why don't you just edit AndroidManifest.xml that Qt Creator creates for you and add it to version control. Creator creates it to sources side not to build side.